# How does cloth simulation work in Blender 2.79?

Tags: cloth-simulation

Due to the limited capabilities of my hardware, I am forced to use Blender version 2.79 and am currently busy studying the settings for cloth simulation. However, the official Blender guide offers very vague descriptions for each of the settings, which do not give an accurate understanding of how exactly they affect the simulation, the behavior of the polygons. Now I'm trying to understand the meaning of each of the settings parameters, just placing random values ​​​​and seeing what happens. But for obvious reasons, it takes too much time. The guides on YouTube, on the other hand, are mainly devoted to newer versions of Blender, where the settings and, as far as I understand, the simulation mechanics themselves have undergone significant changes. I would be grateful if someone from Bender's "olds" would share an understandable guide describing in detail all the cloth simulation settings in Blender 2.7 and demonstrating how they affect the result.

Comment: Plenty of YT videos for 2.79: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBLTXxS_OuQ) for instance. To search Google just add "+2.79" to your search phrase and you get [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=blender+cloth+simulation+%2B2.79) result.

Comment: @JohnEason Among them, there is no comprehensive manual explaining and illustrating each parameter of the modifier in detail. Naturally, I can watch 24 hours of video material from different lessons, where in each of the 20minute videos, only one minute will contain information that is new to me. But for this I turned to this forum: in order to save time and find a lesson or a course that will immediately explain all the intricacies of working with the modifier, and not force you to repeatedly re-read information I already know in different guides in the hope of finding grains of new knowledge

Comment: @JohnEason It got to the point that I simply rewrote all the parameters of interest to me in the search string, placing each one in quotes. And in the end I got only: The aforementioned uninformative official blender guides; Lessons where already set parameters are given to achieve certain results without explaining how and why it works; And some research work on cloth simulation that has no obvious connection with the simulator in the version of blender I need

Comment: This forum is for answering specific problems with using Blender, not for providing detailed tutorials on every aspect of a particular function in Blender. I'm afraid that all we can do is point you to available online information and you'll then have to take it from there.